# the added images lay over each other in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am adding images to the WPF stack panel using the C# code. For positioning the images, I am using `margin` keyword but when I have run the project, a white space for the last image created and push the first image. why?
In the below, I have loaded two images from the same source whit different margins and as you see the first image is covered by the white space from the second image. note that the source Image is a `png` image and has not any with border.

[image]

the code is below(note that I used image control first and then i used the border control and both have the same problem ):

```
Border newLegBorder =new Border();
        BitmapImage casingLegBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/casingleg.png", UriKind.Relative));
        newLegBorder.Background = new ImageBrush(casingLegBitmapImage);
        newLegBorder.Width = casingLegBitmapImage.Width;
        newLegBorder.Height = casingLegBitmapImage.Height;
        newLegBorder.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        newLegBorder.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        newLegBorder.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        newLegBorder.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 100, 0);
        newLegBorder.Width = casingLegBitmapImage.Width;
        newLegBorder.Height = casingLegBitmapImage.Height;
        schematic.Children.Add(newLegBorder);

        Border newLeg2Border = new Border();
        BitmapImage casingLeg2BitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/casingleg.png", UriKind.Relative));
        newLeg2Border.Background = new ImageBrush(casingLeg2BitmapImage);
        newLeg2Border.Width = casingLeg2BitmapImage.Width;
        newLeg2Border.Height = casingLeg2BitmapImage.Height;
        newLeg2Border.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        newLeg2Border.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        newLeg2Border.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        newLeg2Border.Margin = new Thickness(100, 0, 0, 0);
        newLeg2Border.Width = casingLeg2BitmapImage.Width;
        newLeg2Border.Height = casingLeg2BitmapImage.Height;
        schematic.Children.Add(newLeg2Border);


<Window 
    xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerikDocking‌​="clr-namespace:Teler‌​ik.Windows.Controls;a‌​ssembly=Telerik.Windo‌​ws.Controls.Docking" 
    xmlns:System="clr-na‌​mespace:System;assemb‌​ly=mscorlib" 
    xmlns:telerik="http:‌​//schemas.telerik.com‌​/2008/xaml/presentati‌​on" 
    xmlns:Chromes="clr-n‌​amespace:Telerik.Wind‌​ows.Controls.Chromes;‌​assembly=Telerik.Wind‌​ows.Controls" 
    xmlns:Primitives="cl‌​r-namespace:Telerik.Wi‌​ndows.Controls.Primit‌​ives;assembly=Telerik‌​.Windows.Controls.Nav‌​igation" 
    x:Class="imagetoolbo‌​x.wellSchematic" 
    Title="wellSchematic‌​" 
    Height="402" Width="458"> 
    <Grid> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefiniti‌​ons> 
        <ColumnDefinition/> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="236"/> 
    </Grid.ColumnDefinit‌​ions> 
    <StackPanel x:Name="schematic" HorizontalAlignment=‌​"Left" Height="371" VerticalAlignment="T‌​op" Width="214"> 
    </StackPanel> 
    </Grid> 
    </Window>
```

Comment: What were you expecting it to look like?

Comment: I second plast1k's question.

Comment: the images must not lay over. the images must be just like this image:

Comment: desired image is in the below link: http://i66.tinypic.com/28jv2ih.jpg

Comment: Did you try the [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) utility? Using it, you can play with layout in runtime, view the overlay in 3D and understand the problem more easily.

Comment: This so far off from anything that might make sense... Just show your XAML and not the stuff, how you load a brush. This is clearly a Layouting issue

Comment: <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerikDocking="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" xmlns:Chromes="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chromes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls" xmlns:Primitives="clr-

Comment: namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation" x:Class="imagetoolbox.wellSchematic"
        Title="wellSchematic" Height="402" Width="458">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="236"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="schematic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="371" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Comment: the snoop in 3d was showing as below image: http://imgur.com/a/Un18e

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the stackpanel will, well, stack all children. The first image is not covered by the second image, they are merely stacked on top of each other.

To position the images you should use the grid directly, combined with margins and alignments.

Play around with the XAML sample below to get the layout you want, and transfer it to codebehind.

```
<Window
....>
    <Grid x:Name="schematic">
      <!-- First image will stretch vertically -->
      <Image Stretch="Fill" Margin="10,20,0,25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10">
        <Image.Source>
          <BitmapImage UriSource="images/casingleg"/>
        </Image.Source>
      </Image>

      <Image Margin="0,30,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10">
        <Image.Source>
          <BitmapImage UriSource="images/casingleg"/>
        </Image.Source>
      </Image>

      <Image Margin="40,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="10">
        <Image.Source>
          <BitmapImage UriSource="images/casingleg"/>
        </Image.Source>
      </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind for the above sample.

```
public class WellSchematic : UserControl
{
    public WellSchematic()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var im1 = CreateImage();
        im1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        im1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        im1.Margin = new Margin(10,20,0,25);
        im1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

        var im2 = CreateImage();
        im2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        im2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        im2.Margin = new Margin(0,30,20,0);

        var im3 = CreateImage();
        im3.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        im3.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        im3.Margin = new Margin(40,0,0,10);

        // Add more pictures
    }

    private void CreateImage()
    {
        var image = new Image();
        var bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images/casingleg", UriKind.Relative));
        image.Source = bmp;
        image.Width = bmp.Width;
        image.Height = bmp.Height;

        schematic.Children.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi and thank you for your answer. unfortunately, I need to add them in code because it must be changed and the number of images is not pre determined and it must be determined during the running. so it must be added in the code not XAML.

Comment: Ok. In that case, you could consider using an ItemsControl and have a collection of paths to images you bind it to (and change the datatemplate to an image.

Comment: can you provide the example please?

Comment: I have added a sample (I haven't been able to verify it), which should demonstrate using an ItemsControl.

Comment: Ok, then just use your original code behind, but change the orientation of your stackpanel, as per my sample code, and get rid of the margins.

Comment: I think it does not work because both images have been placed in one stackpanel.

Comment: That should not make a difference. A stackpanel can have infinitely many controls inside - hence the Children.Add.

Comment: can you bring the code that add two same image side by side in a stackpanel?

Comment: The sample now shows the minimum required code to show two images side by side, without the noise of borders, margins, grid.row/column. I suggest you start out by creating the layout in xaml, even if you need to do it in code behind. This will allow you to see what your code behind should do. E.g. setting grid.row/col and vertical/horizontal alignments does absolutely nothing inside a stackpanel, because it scales according to it's children.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers. I tried that but it change all the images to be side by side.let me explain with more details. I have some images and I need to order them in different types in a wpf window. as the image could not to be added directly to the window I used the stack panel. my final result must be some like what is shown in this figure. http://imgur.com/a/GXjZM

Comment: @ali Any luck...?

Comment: hi. yes. i used canvases to do that. stack panels do not obey Margins clearly but canvases do and their specific location can be specified clearly by margins at the desired position.